# Deserializing arbitrary JSON with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jackson

I have a JSON clob which I am deserializing into a bean, which is then sent as JSON as the response of an HTTP request.

I would like to add a JSONObject field to the bean which contains arbitrary JSON.

Here is my bean:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DTO implements Serializable {
    private String height;
    private String width;
    //I would like to add this field
    //private JSONObject settings;
```

And here is how I deserialize the CLOB:

```
DTO layout = null;
String json = "{\"height\": \"300px\", \"width\": \"100%\"}";
final ObjectMapper mapper = jackson.getContext(DTO.class);

try {
    layout = mapper.readValue(json, DTO.class);
}
catch(IOException ex) {
    logger.error("Unable to deserialize Dashboard layout CLOB", ex);
}
```

This works.  However, I need my clob to contain a settings object which contains arbitrary JSON.  Is this possible?  For example:

```
 {"height": "300px", "width": "100%", "settings": {"propA": 1, "propB": "red"}}
```

When I try this with JSONObject, I get the error:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid  exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain:  api.jaxb.DTO["settings"])
```

Comment: Do you need to have the fields deserialized into your object or can  you ignore them?

Comment: Your `settings` object should probably be of type `JsonNode` which is part of Jackson and then your deserialization should work fine.

Comment: @MikeKobit this works! If you would like to post this as an answer I'll accept it.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSONObject` comes from the [JSON library](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) which is a separate package than Jackson. In your case you should use [JsonNode](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode.html) from the Jackson library.:

```
public class DTO implements Serializable {
    ...
    private org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode settings;
```